# Lexical Bindings in Common Lisp Macros

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, lexical-scope

I am currently working my way through Graham's On Lisp and find this particular bit difficult to understand:

> **Binding**. Lexical variables must appear directly in the source code. The
>   first argument to `setq` is not evaluated, for example, so anything
>   built on `setq` must be a macro which expands into a `setq`, rather than a
>   function which calls it. Likewise for operators like `let`, whose
>   arguments are to appear as parameters in a lambda expression, for
>   macros like do which expand into `let`s, and so on. Any new operator
>   which is to alter the lexical bindings of its arguments must be
>   written as a macro.

This comes from Chapter 8, which describes when macros should and should not be used in place of functions.

What exactly does he mean in this paragraph? Could someone give a concrete example or two?

Much appreciated!

Comment: As an experience Lisper, I totally understand what that text is *trying* to say, only I cannot parse the actual text. If I run my finger down the middle of the paragraph and just skim it in 0.5 seconds, then it makes sense, but if I pick at the individual words and phrases then it sort of eludes me.

Comment: The "arguments" of a `let` do not appear in a lambda expression, for instance. What?

Comment: Are you saying it is poorly written? This paragraph was an example of a paragraph that no matter how many times I had read it, I still asked myself, "Whaaat?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setq` is a special form and does not evaluate its first argument. Thus if you want to make a macro that updates something, you cannot do it like this:

```
(defun update (what with)
  (setq what with))

(defparameter *test* 10)
(update *test* 20)        ; what does it do?
*test*                    ; ==> 10
```

So inside the function `update` `setq` updates the variable `what` to be `20`, but it is a local variable that has the value `10` that gets updated, not `*test*` itself. In order to update `*test*` `setq` must have `*test*` as first argument. A  macro can do that:

```
(defmacro update (what with)
  `(setq ,what ,with))

(update *test* 20)        ; what does it do?
*test*                    ; ==> 20
```

You can see exactly the resulting code form the macro expansion:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(update *test* 20))
; ==> (setq *test* 20) ; t
```

A similar example. You cannot mimic `if` with `cond` using a function:

```
(defun my-if (test then else)
  (cond (test then)
        (t else)))

(defun fib (n)
  (my-if (< 2 n) 
         n
         (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))

(fib 3)
```

No matter what argument you pass you get an infinite loop that **always** call the recursive case since all `my-if` arguments are always evaluated. With `cond` and `if` the `test` gets evaluated and based on that either the `then` or `else` is evaluated, but never all unconditionally.